# Programmatically attach image to a content type from local system folder

Tags: 7, nodes

I am in middle of coding creating nodes programatically. Here i have one problem. I need to programmatically attach image to the content type from local system folder. I mean my image path example 'c://xxxxx/xxxx/images/img.jpg'.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Hi i used this code and work fine in the localhost. But it's failed when i work on the server.

```
$filepath = drupal_realpath('misc/druplicon.png');
// Create managed File object and associate with Image field.
$file = (object) array(
 'uid' => 1,
 'uri' => $filepath,
 'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($filepath),
 'status' => 1,
);

// We save the file to the root of the files directory.
$file = file_copy($file, 'public://');

$node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;
```

Reference link : [attaching-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7)

> I didn't get the solution yet. Can any one have the experience?

Comment: Did you check your file permissions to make sure you can copy into the folder?  admin/config/media/file-system

Comment: Also check your logs to see if there is any error messages in there.  admin/reports/dblog

Answer (score 1):

You can just use file_copy or file_move.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a code like this:

```
$filepath = 'TheFilePath';
$file = new stdClass();
$file->filename = basename($filepath);
$file->filepath = $filepath;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($filepath);
$file->filesize = filesize($filepath);
$file->uid = 1;
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file->uri = $filepath;
$file->display = 1;
$file->description = '';
$file = file_copy($file, 'public://news-images', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

$node->field_article_picture[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = (array)$file;
```

And it works...so I hope it helps for you too!